# Application not connecting to Worklight server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

[image]I am using WL.Client.connect(options) to connect to worklight server from my hybrid app and its returing this error (please refer to the attachment).
I have checked the WL console, my app and adapters are deployed without any issues.
Could not find any error messages in the logs.

```
function performWlConnect() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // Worklight server connection callback configuration
        var wlConnectOptions = {
            onSuccess: resolve,
            onFailure: reject
        };

        logger.info('Connecting to the worklight server side...');
        // Perform connection to the server side
        WL.Client.connect(wlConnectOptions);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the image, just added it.

Comment: Still not enough information. Provide your code as well as mention where are you testing this.

Comment: Added the code snippet, and we are testing it in Android device.

Comment: any specific trace that we need to enable to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple connect and print the error you're getting, it might help you better diagnose your flow.

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Client.connect({onSuccess:onConnectSuccess, onFailure:onConnectFailure});
}

function onConnectSuccess() {
    ...
}

function onConnectFailure(response) {
    WL.Logger.debug(response);
}
```